# How to get Spring to create AOP Proxies for my beans

Tags: java, spring, aop

In my Spring application, I have a whole bunch of beans (in this case DAOs) that are created as simple `<bean>`s in my XML configuration. In these methods are various annotations, including specifically `@Transactional`. I naturally have `<tx:annotation-driven />` as well.

But for some of these objects - though only some of them - no proxies are created (I confirmed this by enabling debug logging) and the `@Transactional` annotation has no effect. Instead the objects that contain (usually autowired) references to these DAOs get wired a reference to the direct class, not a proxy.

All of the classes have corresponding interfaces and the autowired references are always through these interfaces.

I can't figure out which classes get the proxies and which don't. I want them all to. So my question is:

a) under what circumstances does Spring not create a proxy for a class even though it implements some interfaces?

b) how can I force Spring to create the proxies I need?

Note that I have not done anything to explicitly enable proxying, but I haven't needed to in the past. It usually just works.

Tried with both Spring 3.1.3 and 3.2.2.

I don't have a SSCCE for this. Essentially my XML is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"       
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"    
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"                       
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"       
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
       http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
">

       <bean id="userDao" class="com.soschat.dao.spring.SpringUserDAO"/>

           <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class=" org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="false" />
    </bean>

... etc ...
</beans>
```

and my code is more or less

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

   @Override
   @Transactional
   @Cacheable
   public User getUserById(long userId) {
         // do stuff
   }
}
```

Not sure how much more I need to add in without excessive detail.

One interesting addition - I am able to force it to create the proxy using BeanNameAutoProxyCreator. But none of the annotations I put in there actually take effect.

Comment: Annotate your `UserDaoImpl` class with `@Repository` which is a type of `@Component` and remove your `userDao` bean which I assume is also implementing `UserDao` (you'll get the clash you got earlier). And don't forget `<component-scan>` on that package.

Comment: No luck. The proxy is created but the annotations still don't take effect; neither `@Transactional` nor `@Cacheable`.

Comment: If there was a proxy created, then @Transactional was found. What is telling you that transactions aren't happening?

Comment: TransactionInterceptor doesn't appear in the call stack when I stop inside the DAO method. Or if I set propagation = MANDATORY I should be getting an exception and I'm not.

Comment: In debugger, what does the Dao type look like? Is it `UserDaoImpl ` or some Proxy@! with random chars?

Comment: Why you expect that a bean of type com.soschat.dao.spring.SpringUserDAO become proxied when annotating the the type UserDaoImpl?

Comment: Typo on my part coming from my real code. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I figured out that it was failing because of some kind of dependency chain starting with a bean that was somehow being loaded "too early" -  in my case, a Spring Security `PermissionEvaluator`. I still don't have a SSCCE, but I'm adding this answer here in case someone else had a similar problem.

The solution was to use very-late binding. I made my `PermssionEvaluator` into `ApplicationContextAware`, then wrote a private method to load the local been references from the `ApplicationContext`, and this method is only called when it is first needed, which is not during initialization.

In other words I had a bean like

```
private AuthorizationServices authServices;
```

and then in my main method something like

```
if (authServices == null)
   initBeans();
```

and then

```
private void initBeans() {
    authServices = ac.getBean(AuthorizationServices.class);
}
```

Comment: spring should give some information or interface, when we really could get the proxy, or spring should show some information, the order of how the beans be init

Comment: you could have just used the @Lazy annotation to do the same thing.

Comment: I had a very similar case with a hierarchy of components injected into the Spring DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler and @Lazy did not help. It seems like Spring isn't looking at any annotations in this case.

Comment: I didn't know about @Lazy when I first posted this, but yeah I've ended up using it elsewhere for similar reasons, and usually it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The `@Component` annotation will tell Spring to create and process a bean of that class. You'll need to have your application (or other) context scan that class' package with the `<component-scan>` element.

`@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` work just like `@Component`.

As for proxying, Spring doesn't proxy everything, only instances of classes it needs to add behavior to. For example, with `@Transactional`, it needs to add begin/commit/rollback transaction behavior. To do this it wraps your class' methods with its own code, so it needs to proxy. For a `@Controller` class, it doesn't need to add any behavior, so it'll simply instantiate your class.

Comment: So how does it know which classes to proxy in the absence of `@Component`? As I said, the classes I'm seeing this with do have `@Transactional` on some of their methods.

Comment: In the absence of `@Component`, Spring does nothing with that class.

Comment: Also, do I really need `<component-scan>` when I'm defining beans explicitly using `<bean>`?

Comment: @Dan I would think so. It's not like it would to do any harm if you didn't need it.

Comment: It seems to in my case: getting org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.dao.MyDAOInterface] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: myDaoInterface,myDao

Comment: @Dan Aha. With `@Component`, Spring will make a bean for you. You also have your own bean definition. So you get 2 beans. You're better off with the `@Component`.

Comment: Tried, still no luck. My bean is not getting proxied.

Comment: @Dan Can you update your question with your spring contexts and the class you are expecting to be proxied?

Comment: Added some stuff. Take a look. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue and realized that the bean was initialized before org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager in the application start-up, hence @Cacheable was not working.

We ended up moving cache configuration to xml from java configuration class which forced (not sure how), EHCacheManager initialization before any of the application beans. We have both xml and java configuration in our application.

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml" p:shared="true"/>
```